# Getting List Column Does Not Exist Error When The Column Very Clearly Exists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, splistitem, sharepoint-list

Running a query to add a list item. When setting columns in a list I set a column named '2138023830'. It is the hash code of a string. This is the code that sets it:

```
for( var i = 0; i < $scope.optionalQuestions.length; i++ ) {
    console.log("Setting optional question with index " + i);
    if( optionalBodyClicked[i] ) {
        newCourseReviewItem.set_item($scope.optionalQuestions[i].hashCode().toString(), $scope.optionalTextAreaTexts[i]);
    } else {
        newCourseReviewItem.set_item($scope.optionalQuestions[i].hashCode().toString(), "");
    }
}
```

later on I update and load, and then execute the query:

```
newCourseReviewItem.update();
context.load(newCourseReviewItem);

context.executeQueryAsync(
    submitCourseReviewSuccess,
    submitCourseReviewFail
);
```

When I actually run the code, here'e the error I get:

[image]

Okay well that column there does exist, I don't know what crack SharePoint is smoking (hint: every kind). Here is proof if you don't believe me:

[image]

Btw, the list Course-Reviews is stored at /teams/OBDev/Lists/CourseReviews so the correct URL is being accessed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in and check the internal name of the column. You can do this by editing the column and looking at the **Field** parameter in the url. In my case when I created a column with that name the internal name began with **_x003**, which is, I think, the ascii character for `end of text`

Generally I think it is best to not start column names with numbers or special characters.

Comment: Fixed by changing the hash function to return positive integers only and adding a letter at the start of the field names. Spot on thank you.

Comment: You'll also want to keep the hash and letter shorter than 32 characters. I think that is the limit on internal name length.